# Container inline-block once again

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline

[Look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W0tJ.png)

I would like to make a main container that has 2 sub containers - left and right (each 50% of the screen width).

Left must contain a photo. The right one must contain the text (h2 and p directly below). The text should be halfway up the image.

I need it to describe the products in the store.

I was trying this

```
div { border: 1px solid #CCC; }

<div style="display: inline">a</div>
<div style="display: inline">b</div>
<div style="display: inline">c</div>
```

but in this case I could not type h2 and p in the same div.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide drawing or jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using flexbox.

```css
.container {
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container > div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.right__content * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x150" alt="left img">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
     <div class="right__content">
       <h1>Header text</h1>
       <p>my desc</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It looks great! I would be grateful for the example where the text is on the left and the image is on the right. This must be the second container below the previous one. Once the text on the right and once on the left. The first container is the one from your example. @Toxnyc

Comment: And one more question. How to move text under an image in the case of narrow screens. Is it possible in your solution? @Toxnyc

Comment: You could do `flex-direction: row-reverse` in the container to make the text to the left, or simply modify your HTML. You can learn about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: You could use media query to detect narrow screens and just add `flex-direction: column;` to the container so that they stack. Or you could just make the container to wrap itself using `flex-wrap: wrap`, but you might need to set a min-width for the left/right element.

Answer (score 1):

Grid, in my humble opinion, is the right tool for what you are asking to use it for. It is a bit newer than flexbox I believe, and it takes a little getting use to, but your whole web-development world is going to change if you take the time to learn it (doesn't take but 8-12 hours of playing with it to grasp the concepts). Anywho, below is how I would do it. To learn more about CSS GRID,check out

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

CHEERS MATE!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #DDD;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 8px;
            background-color: #777;
            border: 2px solid #f00;
        }

        .left {
            text-align: center;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 8px;
            background-color: #777;
            border: 2px solid #0f0;
        }

        .right {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 8px;
            background-color: #777;
            border: 2px solid #00f;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            .grid-container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr !important;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        <p>
            Mollis in natoque phasellus nec pellentesque adipiscing ante rhoncus, 
            penatibus molestie inceptos arcu vulputate auctor dolor. Mollis fames malesuada 
            torquent adipiscing consectetur venenatis eu gravida eget, leo phasellus tristique 
            tempus ad facilisi non blandit habitasse, per lectus lobortis primis consequat urna 
            ac pretium. Fames elementum ullamcorper sem nisl vel erat potenti dignissim, nec 
            dictum luctus libero posuere nunc commodo odio facilisi, torquent venenatis
            pellentesque metus ultricies senectus turpis. Consectetur arcu montes non 
            sagittis sociis pulvinar condimentum dictumst, integer duis adipiscing praesent 
            diam hendrerit vel enim suspendisse, per dis rutrum urna maecenas porttitor senectus.
        </p>

        <p>
            Ja, ni gör som ni vill, men jag rår inte för att jag hela livet gått på rosor. Niklas tog tag 
            i datorn och lyfte den mot himmeln. Om vädret inte var så dåligt skulle vi aldrig få något  
            klaga på. Galna kossor lever glatt på åkern i norra Stockholm. Tar upp en liten pall, som 
            tår vid bordet på högra sidan. Han tog tag i den röda skiftnyckeln och slog hårt på muren. 
            Glada bläckfiskar hoppar alltid upp för strömmen när de är på väg hemåt.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You asked in your comment how to make it responsive for narrower screens so I did. It will now stack because I added an @media query, which tells it to repond to the screen being 800px or less. Then I changed the grid container. Instead of grid-columns being side by side, which I set using the syntax:

```
 grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
```

I changed it to being :

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
```

The change switches it from a split container at 50% of the screen size each. To single containers containing only 1fr(which means just one whole container). And since they take up the whole screen width they now stack, and grid automatically wraps the containers for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to move text under an image in the case of narrow screens. Is it possible in your solution? @Aft3rL1f3

Comment: So if you want to build a responsive webpage pae you have to add an @media query. I will add another example bellow