# Box Sizing with divs

Tags: css

I have two divs side by side. With an display:Inline-Block; attach to it. However when i place content inside them the content is not centered. I have attached an screen shot that shows what im talking about. I want the content on the right to be centered in the box. Any suggestions

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFmp2.png)

Comment: Your question is similar to this one. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59474441/8606992

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container inline-block once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474124/container-inline-block-once-again)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```css
.two-boxes-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.box-1, .box-2 {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-boxes-wrapper">

    <div class="box-1">
       <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517705008128-361805f42e86?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=679&q=80">
        
    </div>


      <div class="box-2">
         <div class="content">
          <p class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum,</p>
        
        
          <h2 class="h3">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum </h2>
        
<p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. </p>
          
<p><a href="#" class="button btn">Read </a></p>
</div></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem ChristopherKerr

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using flexbox to lay out your divs so that they will always be centered with each other:

```css
.container {
  width: 750px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10vh auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding: .5rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <p>this is some text that can go here. or you can put an image here. whatever you want.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>this is also some text. whatever you want can go here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```